# where are jQuery css changes tracked

Tags: jquery, html, css

Just wondering, when using `jQuery.css()` to dynamically modify the styling of a page, where these changes are tracked. Do these get applied to the element in an inline fashion or is there some temporary css file that jQuery creates to track these changes?

the reason I'm asking is because I want to know if I can access that data

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/: _“When using `.css()` as a setter, jQuery modifies the element's style property. For example, `$( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "green" )` is equivalent to `document.getElementById( "mydiv" ).style.color = "green"`.”_

Comment: @CBroe good stuff, thank you for the link and quote!!! just what I was looking for

Comment: @CBroe That comment qualifies as an answer, you should add it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the jQuery docs at http://api.jquery.com/css/:

> “When using `.css()` as a setter, jQuery modifies the element's style property. For example, `$( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "green" )` is equivalent to `document.getElementById( "mydiv" ).style.color = "green"`.”

So these changes are not “tracked” anywhere specifically by jQuery – rather the browser itself “tracks” them, as it would with any style set via an element’s `style` attribute directly. When the selector matches multiple elements, then jQuery will set the `style` for each element individually.

And as such, those styles can be read back from there if necessary – again, using `.css()`, just as a getter with just the first parameter.